# Select *Help* window buffer after C-h f

Tags: help-mode

I do "C-h f" a lot for emacs lisp functions. I prefer to have the window displaying the *Help* buffer selected (right after C-h f) and then press "q" when im done to close the window. Is there a way to achive this?

Comment: Mildly related: you can use https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-link to
navigate `*Help*` buffer once you're there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try

```
(setq help-window-select t)
```

or customize this variable. The full documentation states:

```
Documentation:
Non-nil means select help window for viewing.
Choices are:
 never (nil) Select help window only if there is no other window
             on its frame.
 other       Select help window unless the selected window is the
             only other window on the help window's frame.
 always (t)  Always select the help window.

This option has effect if and only if the help window was created
by `with-help-window'

You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 23.1 of Emacs.
```

Comment: Good to know this is a built-in feature "now"!  For ages I used an advice for the various help functions to do this.